# Determining the "variability" of a benchmark

Tags: variance

I have a software benchmark which is quite noisy. I am trying to for the bugs which are causing the noise, and I need to be able to measure it somehow.

The benchmark is comprised of a number of subbenchmarks, for example:

```
"3d-cube": 31.56884765625,
"3d-morph": 21.89599609375,
"3d-raytrace": 51.802978515625,
"access-binary-trees": 15.09521484375,
"access-fannkuch": 45.578857421875,
"access-nbody": 8.651123046875,
```

The times are in milliseconds. The times typically vary between runs. For example, on my machine, the "3d-cube" benchmark tends to take around 35ms, but I've seen it go as high as 44ms, and 31ms (above) is uncharacteristically low.

My aim is to change the benchmark so that minor improvements to the run-time can be visible in a benchmark result. What I need is a number that tells me whether I have reduced the "variability" of the benchmark.

#### My own solution

I run it the benchmark 1000 times, the took the sum of the differences between each subbenchmark's mean and its actual run-times. In pseudo-code:

```
v = 0
for s in subbenchmarks:
  x = mean of all iterations of s
  for i in iteration
    v += absolute_value(results[s][i] - x)
```

I'm sure this isn't statistically valid (having asked someone), but what is a "correct" way of measuring this "variability" so that I can reduce it.

Comment: An amusing observation: all your benchmark times are multiples of 2^-12 (=1/4096).

Comment: @whuber: must be the maximum resolution - a quarter of a microsecond ain't bad! 22-bits resolution-ish?

Comment: @whuber: you're clearly spending too much time on stats.SE :P

Answer (score 5):

As gd047 mentioned, the standard way of measuring variability is to use the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance). So your pseudo-code will be:

```
vnew = vector of length subbenchmarks
for s in subbenchmarks:
  vnew[i] = variance(s)
```

Now the problem is, even if  you don't change your code, `vnew` will be different for each run - there is noise. To determine if a change is significant, we need to perform a [hypothesis test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing), i.e. can the change be explained as random variation or is likely that something has changed. A quick and dirty rule would be:

\begin{equation}
Y_i = \sqrt{n/2} \left(\frac{vnew_i}{vold_i} -1\right) \sim N(0,1)
\end{equation}

This means any values of $Y_i < -1.96$ (at a 5% significance level) can be considered significant, i.e. an improvement. However, I would probably increase this to -3 or -4. This would test for improvement in **individual** benchmarks.

If you want to combine all your benchmarks into a single test, then let

\begin{equation}
\bar Y = \frac{1}{n} \sum Y_i
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n} \bar Y \sim N(0, 1)
\end{equation}

Hence, an appropriate test would be to consider values of $\bar Y < 1.96$ to indicate an improvement.

---

**Edit**

If the benchmarks aren't Normal, then I would try working with log(benchmarks). It also depends on what you want to do. I read your question as "You would like a good rule of thumb". In this case, taking logs is probably OK.

---

1. Further details of the mathematical reasoning are found at Section 3.2 of this [document](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105042452/http://dsmts.googlecode.com/files/dsmts-userguide31.pdf).
2. I've made a approximation by assuming that v_old represents the true underlying variance.

Comment: I'm told that the results of the benchmarks (the times in ms) are not normally distributed. Will the variances be normally distributed? How does that affect the choice of 1.96?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your method is the one described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_deviation), and it's apparently valid. You could also have used the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) as a measure of variability (which according to the article, it's not as [robust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) as your absolute deviation)

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion), for other measures of statistical dispersion.

Comment: I would go with variance and/or standard deviation (sd is just the square root of the variance) instead of the absolute deviation, because variance and sd punish extreme outliers stronger. This seems desirable in your case.

Comment: When I go with standard deviation or variance, I come up with the problem of how to combine the results for the subbenchmarks into a whole. Absolute variance (assuming that's what I did) gives me a single number.

Comment: Note that I tried to combine my sub-variances using "the variance of the total is the mean of the variances of the subgroups + variance of the means of the subgroups", which I got from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance.

Comment: A strong case can be made for robust techniques that do the opposite of "punishing" outliers, because outliers in benchmarks often occur unavoidably due to other processes and external perturbations causing a process to wait from time to time.  This could be the reason the benchmarks do not appear to be normally distributed, too.  However, as cgillespie's answer points out, you can go a long way with the standard hypothesis testing machinery applied to SDs.  As a compromise, a lightly Winsorized version of the SD might be a good choice.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorising )